# Why does this mod rewrite cause an internal server error?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could anyone please let me know what is wrong with the below code I am putting into my .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^New_Hampshire/[a-zA-Z0-9_+ -]+\.html$ NH/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the -, and put in \s for whitespace

```
RewriteRule ^New_Hampshire/[a-zA-Z0-9_+\-\s]+\.html$ NH/
```

Comment: I was told you don't need to escape the hyphen if it is the last character in a character class?

Comment: You don't need to escape the hyphen if it is the *first* character in a character class.

Comment: @Brett, you were told right: it was the unescaped space that was causing the error, not the hyphen.  But the correct solution is to escape the space with a backslash or replace it with `\s`, which matches any whitespace character.  `\w` is the escape sequence for a word character (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).